# pagebeforehide event fired just for "inner" page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to do something when leaving page (page '#first').
It's really simple:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforehide', '#first', function(event, ui) {alert('leaving page');});
```

No problem when I leave page by "inner" links something like this one:

```
<a href="#second" data-role="button">Open something</a>
```

here event fired and handler executed.

But when I want to open external link like this one:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="external" data-role="button">Open something</a>
```

here event not fired and handler not executed.

Doesn't matter is page content simple or complex - I found that this depends only on fact whether link inner or external.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rel="external" means that page will be opened as an external page and all previous page content (including its scripts) will be lost, that will also trigger a full page refresh so your **pagebeforehide** event is not going to trigger because it will no longer exist.

jQuery Mobile page events can occur only during normal page changes. Basically what I want to say is you need to go to the other jQuery Mobile page for this event to trigger. In your case you are forcing app to do a full page refresh, at this point, page refresh will occur before **pagebeforehide** event.

**EDIT :**

While there isn't any crossbrowser solution for this you can always cheat.

1. Instead of having href link inside your button, replace your link http://www.google.com with # and add it an id so we can identify it,  like this:

   Open something

Now add a click event to this button and do what ever needs to be done before changing page to www.google.com:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#change-page', function(){       
        // Do something here then change page
    });
```

1. Or link your button to another dummy inner page (use this inner page only for this purpose), catch pagebeforehide on it:

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforehide ', function(){       
       // Again do something here and manualy change the page
   });
   ```

Comment: Can you advice some SAFE (meant: browser independent) way to trap transition between pages?
It's really important because Google Chrome doesn't support DOM `onunload` event, mobile Safari (iOS devices) doesn't support `onbeforeunload` event etc

Comment: You are out of luck because there isn't any similar crossbrowser implementation. But that should not prevent you from cheating. I will write possible solutions into my answer.

Comment: Click handling is the evident case to handle page transitions.
Evident but not cover all possible ways - transitions using browser Back / Forward button and closing page.
Is it final - cross-browser implementation for trap page transitions in common sense (!) doesn't exist?

Comment: Lets look at this from an other perspective. If browser developers can't get along with css3/html5 implementations why would they agree over java script questions? Do not relay on any technology younger then 3 years.